# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addAdvogado' was called on null. On Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, null, nosuchmethoderror

I researched other similar questions with this error but I couldn't fix it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
My application is not saving to the database when I try to send the information to the form.
What should I do to correct?

I receive the message:

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addAdvogado' was
> called on null. E/flutter ( 7418): Receiver: null E/flutter ( 7418):
> Tried calling: addAdvogado(Instance of 'Advogado')

**lawyer.dart**

```
class Advogado {
  final String id;
  final String nome;
  final String email;
  final String telefone;
  final String endereco;
  final String numeroOAB;

  const Advogado(
      {this.id,
      @required this.nome,
      @required this.email,
      @required this.telefone,
      @required this.endereco,
      @required this.numeroOAB});

  Advogado.fromMap(Map snapshot, String id)
      : id = snapshot['id'] ?? '',
        nome = snapshot['nome'] ?? '',
        email = snapshot['email'] ?? '',
        telefone = snapshot['telefone'] ?? '',
        endereco = snapshot['endereco'] ?? '',
        numeroOAB = snapshot['numeroOAB'] ?? '';

  toJson() {
    return {
      "id": id,
      "nome": nome,
      "email": email,
      "telefone": telefone,
      "endereco": endereco,
      "numeroOAB": numeroOAB,
    };
  }
}
```

**form_lawyer.dart - Sample code**

```
final _formAdvogado = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final Map<String, String> _dadosForm = {};
    Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formAdvogado.currentState.validate()) {
                      _formAdvogado.currentState.save();
                      await advogadoProvider.addAdvogado(
                        Advogado(
                          nome: 'nome',
                          email: 'email',
                          telefone: 'telefone',
                          endereco: 'endereco',
                          numeroOAB: 'numeroOAB',
                        ),
                      );
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("Enviar"),
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                ),
```

**api_lawyer_firebase.dart**

```
class ApiFirebase {
  // final FirebaseFirestore _bd = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialize = Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseFirestore _bd = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;

  ApiFirebase(this.path) {
    ref = _bd.collection(path);
  }

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getColecaoDados() {
    return ref.get();
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamColecaoDados() {
    return ref.snapshots();
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getDocumentoById(String id) {
    return ref.doc(id).get();
  }

  Future<void> removerDocumento(String id) {
    return ref.doc(id).delete();
  }

  Future<DocumentReference> addDocumento(Map dados) {
    return ref.add(dados);
  }

  Future<void> atualizarDocumento(Map dados, String id) {
    return ref.doc(id).update(dados);
  }
}
```

**CRUD - database_laywer.dart**

```
class DBAdvogado with ChangeNotifier {
  ApiFirebase _apiFirebase = locator<ApiFirebase>();

  List<Advogado> advogados;

  Future<List<Advogado>> buscarAdvogados() async {
    var result = await _apiFirebase.getColecaoDados();
    advogados =
        result.docs.map((doc) => Advogado.fromMap(doc.data(), doc.id)).toList();
    return advogados;
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> buscarAdvogadoAsStream() {
    return _apiFirebase.streamColecaoDados();
  }

  Future<Advogado> getAdvogadoById(String id) async {
    var doc = await _apiFirebase.getDocumentoById(id);
    return Advogado.fromMap(doc.data(), doc.id);
  }

  Future removerAdvogado(Advogado dados, String id) async {
    await _apiFirebase.atualizarDocumento(dados.toJson(), id);
    return;
  }

  Future addAdvogado(Advogado dados) async {
    await _apiFirebase.addDocumento(dados.toJson());
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when there is an error with *"something" was called on null* it means that the subject on which you are calling "something" is currently null.

You use `addAdvogado` method in one place on only one variable - in `form_lawyer.dart` on `advogadoProvider`. So the question is: **how and where do you set `advogadoProvider`?**

Comment: Yes i wrote the methods and variables in portuguese since i am brazilian. I hope I haven't been confused who read my question.